# How can I stop an object in my application being disposed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dispose

I have a user control with an ActiveX control on it. Due to the amount of time it takes to load the ActiveX control I thought what I can do is create an instance of the user control on application startup. Then when I wanted to use that user control I would just use the instance that I created. This works fine until I close a form where the instance was used. It disposes of it (as far as I can tell)

so when I try to use it again I can't. I wondered if it was possible to mark it in some way not to get disposed of on form close?

The exact message I get when trying to use it again is :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: 'COM object
>   that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.'

Or if there is another/better way to acheieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: The only way to keep it alive is to remove it from the form's Controls collection before the form closes.  Consider the FormClosing event.  Be sure to not lose track of it, a Shared variable is suitable if there is only ever one of that control.  Adding it back to a form is special as well, you can't use the designer anymore.  Do so in Sub New, after the InitializeComponent() call.  It might not necessarily deal well with getting another parent, expect trouble.

Comment: Thank you, so far it seems to be working as I would like by removing it from the controls on closing. There is only 3 forms that use it so it's not too difficult to keep track fortunately. They get used quite frequently though which is why I want to do this in the first place otherwise I would just have the user wait the 4-5 seconds it takes to load each time. Hopefully this will be the solution. It doesn't allow me to have it on 2 forms at the same time (which i expected) but again fortunately it doesn't need to be on any other form at the same time. I just wanted to see if it could.